# Вводя значение больше чем вмещает инт, программа в дальнейшем игнорирует все cin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Нужно сделать проверки на введеные значения,что бы пользователь не мог вводить числа, которые не поместятся в таблицу или не подойдут по условию. Сделал после ввода `cin >> exmpl[i].Number_of_products;` просто  `if (exmpl[i].Number_of_products > 255)` оно работало аналогично коду снизу. Проблема в том, что все дальнейшие `cin >>` тупо игнорируются. Уже пробовал и обнулять вводимое значение, а затем с помощью goto давать новую попытку, но ничего не работает, хелп.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct TABLE_UNIT {
    char firm[12];
    int Number_of_products;
    long Annual_sales;
    float Part_of_the_market;
};

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    TABLE_UNIT exmpl[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введіть назву Фірми #" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> exmpl[i].firm;
        cout << "Введіть Кількість продуктів(число до 255) Фірми #" << i + 1 << endl;
        //cin >> exmpl[i].Number_of_products;
        try 
        {
            cin >> exmpl[i].Number_of_products;
            if (exmpl[i].Number_of_products > 255)
            {
                throw 1; 
            }
        }
        catch (int i)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка № " << i << " Число більше 255" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Введіть Річний об’єм продажу ($) Фірми #" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> exmpl[i].Annual_sales;
        cout << "Введіть Частина ринку (%) Фірми #" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> exmpl[i].Part_of_the_market;
    }
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|Фірми – виробники СКБД                                                     |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|Фірма       |Кількість продуктів|Річний об’єм продажу ($)|Частина ринку (%%)|\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|%-12s|%-19i|%-24i|%-17.1f|\n", exmpl[0].firm, exmpl[0].Number_of_products, exmpl[0].Annual_sales, exmpl[0].Part_of_the_market);
    printf("|%-12s|%-19i|%-24i|%-17.1f|\n", exmpl[1].firm, exmpl[1].Number_of_products, exmpl[1].Annual_sales, exmpl[1].Part_of_the_market);
    printf("|%-12s|%-19i|%-24i|%-17.1f|\n", exmpl[2].firm, exmpl[2].Number_of_products, exmpl[2].Annual_sales, exmpl[2].Part_of_the_market);
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|Примітки: за даними Gartner Group за 1999р                                 |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем `typedef` который ничего не `typedef`-ит?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Ввел `300` - все работает. О каком "тупо игнорируются" вы ведете речь? Что вы вводили? Почему в вопросе отсутствует пример входных данных, на которых проявляется проблема?

Comment: у вас все происходит в цикле, поэтому  код должен работать, только нужно инициализировать массив  TABLE_UNIT exmpl[3] = {TABLE_UNIT()}; а то вы работаете с несуществующим обьектом...

Comment: @AnT в заголовке все четко написано, "больше, чем вмещает инт", введите 1000000000000000 и тому подобное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как чтение завершилось ошибкой, поток переходит в состояние [fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/). Для того, чтобы вернутся в состояние [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) используйте [`std::ios::clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/).

```
std::cin.clear();
```

[Пример](https://rextester.com/ZDFXX12444)